# Can IBM Worklight Mobile build faster

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

Currently I am using Eclipse. Can I use another IDE or a customized configuration for Eclipse to build for my project faster? I want to increase my production time.

Answer (score 1):

Worklight 6.2 and above provide a command line interface which you can use instead of Eclipse.
With some development effort you could also take the CLI and hook it to other IDEs that provide pluggability options.

You can read more about the CLI, here:

- For Worklight 6.2: [Command Line Interface for IBM Worklight Developers](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_wl_cli_features.html)
- For MobilFirst 6.3 and above: [Using CLI to create, build, and manage MobileFirst project artifacts](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-all-tutorials-7-0/)